# Cannot convert Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint to System.Windows.Point

Tags: c#, kinect

I cannot figure out how to convert the Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint Type to System.Windows.Point Type. How do I do it?

Cheers

EDIT: What I am trying to do is to create a program that uses the connect to let a user use their hands to draw on a canvas. The problem I am currently having is that whenever I call the `GetPosition` method for the drawing part (So that I can get the current position of the user's hand) it wants a `Point`. The problem is that the `SkeletonStream` returns a `SkeletonPoint` and I am trying to convert it to a `Point` object so that I can pass it to the `GetPosition` method.

Comment: We can't see your screen so you have to describe what you “cannot figure out”. You tagged this “C#”; do you know how to write a C# program? What did you try? What happened?

Comment: There's no magic.  Create a new `Point` with the property values from the existing `SkeletonPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to map the point to the proper space first. Your code can be similar to:

```
DepthImagePoint depthPoint = Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skeletonPoint.Position
                , Kinect.DepthStream.Format);

Point mappedPoint = new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
```